# Fusion Chart: Chart lines overlap when there are same values for graph lines

Tags: asp.net, charts, fusioncharts

I'm using fusion chart free and facing one issue that chart lines overlap each other when there are same values for those lines. Please see below the image where you can see four graph lines (Reputation, Quality of Instruction, Value of Job, Would seek repeat work) overlaps as there are same values for all four lines.

[image]

Is there any ways to convey internet Users graphically that there are same values for all four lines and that's why showing only one line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the values of the data plot in the MSLine chart are same then then lines will overlap and the resultant viewable plot will be a single line.

However, you can notice the number of data sets by viewing the Legend element in the chart.